# Add a Virtual Column to table with XMLType column Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c, xmltype

I have the need to create a new table to store the incoming XML message and am planning to add some virtual columns in the create table statement itself.  This works great!  I have been searching and could not find a way to alter this table to add a new Virtual Column.  Searching on google let me to [this page](http://www.liberidu.com/blog/2007/12/21/virtual-columns-and-binary-xml-storage-schema-validation/)

But that is from 2007 and I wonder if this functionality is now available in Oracle 12c.  Anyone tried this before and have any suggestions?  Thanks!

Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE Import_Log (message_guid varchar2(36),
                 xml_data XMLType)
  XMLTYPE xml_data STORE AS BINARY XML
  VIRTUAL COLUMNS
  (policynumber AS (XMLCast(XMLQuery('/PolicyMessage/Policy/PolicyNumber'
                               PASSING xml_data RETURNING CONTENT)
                      AS VARCHAR2(14))),
   effective_date AS (XMLCast(XMLQuery('/PolicyMessage/Policy/PolicyEffectiveDate'
                               PASSING xml_data RETURNING CONTENT)
                      AS DATE )),
   expiration_date AS (XMLCast(XMLQuery('/PolicyMessage/Policy/PolicyExpirationDate'
                               PASSING xml_data RETURNING CONTENT)
                      AS DATE ))
   );
```

-- The above works fine.

Now if I want to add a new Virtual Column, the only way appears to be to drop and re-create the table which might not be easy down the line.

Comment: Is the questions about adding a virtual column of a "regular" type or an XML type?

Comment: It will be the same as the existing virtual columns pre-defined during the creation of the table like PolicyNumber, Effective_Date etc.

Comment: As a workaround I ended up creating a view with the "new" columns defined since I can re-create the view anytime without any loss of data.  Still would like to know if this can be achieved using alter table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Import_Log (message_guid varchar2(36),
  2                   xml_data XMLType)
  3    XMLTYPE xml_data STORE AS BINARY XML
  4    VIRTUAL COLUMNS
  5    (policynumber AS (XMLCast(XMLQuery('/PolicyMessage/Policy/PolicyNumber'
  6                                 PASSING xml_data RETURNING CONTENT)
  7                        AS VARCHAR2(14))),
  8     effective_date AS (XMLCast(XMLQuery('/PolicyMessage/Policy/PolicyEffectiveDate'
  9                                 PASSING xml_data RETURNING CONTENT)
 10                        AS DATE ))
 11  );

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> alter table import_log
  2  add (
  3        expiration_date generated always AS (XMLCast(XMLQuery('/PolicyMessage/Policy/PolicyExpirationDate'
  4                                 PASSING xml_data RETURNING CONTENT)
  5                        AS DATE )) virtual
  6  )
  7  ;

Table altered.
```

Comment: Thanks BobC.  But looks like this adds it as a regular column and not virtual?

Comment: Thanks!  Just what I was looking for.

Comment: NP. Please consider upvoting